# Error running ProjectTests: Target package is not specified in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-studio

I just installed AndroidStudio 1.8 which provides functionality for running unittests. It runs my unittests, but when I try to debug a test, I get the following error:

> error running tests: targetpackage is not specified in manifest

I have created a new project with AndroidStudio. This will put the packages in the src/main/java directory.

As explained in: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Testing I have to put my unittests in the same packages in src/intstrumentTest/java

I use a default AndroidTest configuration.

When I look at the generated AndroidManifest.xml for my tests I see the correct targetPackage in the intrumentation tag.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the [release notes](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio018released), AS 0.1.8 only supports running tests, not debugging them. Debugging tests is expected to be there in 0.1.9.

EDIT: 0.1.9 with debugging support has been released now.

Comment: Ah, I see. Just overlooked that line. Let's wait for the next release then. Thanks!